# Suppose f is a multiplicative function such that, for odd primes p, f(p) = 3p

Tags: number-theory

How would one go about this question? I am unsure of what to do.
[image: Full Question here]
Would you do for f(11)

- f(11)= f(8)+f(p), where p=1
- f(11)= 9x3(1)  = 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(11)=3\times 11 =33$$
$$f(64)=f(2^6)=0$$ because $6>3$. 
$$f(100)=f(4\times 5^2)=f(4)\times f(5^2)=5\times 2=10$$
$$f(80)=f(2^4\times 5)=f(2^4)\times f(5)=0\times (3\times 5)=0$$

Comment: For f(64), why must 6>3?

Comment: Because $f(2^k)=0$ for $k>3$.

Answer (score 1):

$p=11$ is an odd prime, so $f(11) = 3\cdot 11 = 33$